# Starman's Tesla prelaunch preparation

Tags: spacex, launch, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster, nonstandard-payload

How did they prepare the Tesla before launch? At minimum did they deflate the tires? Removed all liquids and batteries? What about all the materials used on it?How will they react to such friendly temperatures and rays?

Side question: Is there anywhere in the trajectory point, where if flight fails, parts of Tesla can reach the Earth not burnt? I know it is quite small in comparison to the hull, but the point is to know if this is the safest test cargo (if not the most rational one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elon Musk gave a press conference where he talks about a lot of things, this being one of them. According to him the car has not been modified in any way. The full press conference can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sytrrdOPYzA), and the question where Elon talks about this is asked at around 4:50 in the video.

If the Tesla did re-enter Earth's atmosphere it would certainly burn up completely before reaching the surface, almost everything does so.

Comment: Wouldn't the tires explode in vacuum?

Comment: The normal tire pressure of cold Tesla roadster tires is slightly less than 3 bars. With normal atmospheric pressure being one bar the pressure differential is about 2 bars. Going into space — thus losing the surrounding pressure goes to 0 bars, this pressure differential is 3 bars. So essentially the tires are "overinflated" by only 1 bar. But then also take into account that the tires will lose their heat. With no atmosphere to warm them through conduction, and only part of the tires illuminated by the Sun part of the time, this will probably not be enough to keep the tires at at cosy 20°C.

Comment: So the tires will cool, with that their pressure will drop, and thus the "over-inflation" will less than 1 bar. Of course if the temperature drops below the tires' operating specification we do not know how that will affect the rubber, so they may become brittle / weakened and eventually pop.

Comment: I wondered if any foam interior would expand also.

Comment: Removing all liquids was a good idea, but this may be considered as no modification.

Comment: @PhilipNgai Exact timestamp is 5:49 and the quote is "It's literally just a normal car in space."